# Change Email Address and Name Fields from required to not required during uploading of records

Tags: drupal, import, email

Newbie here :)

It appears that the following fields are required when you upload records:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address

I have records to upload that some of the records do not have a First Name, Last Name and/or Email Address.

Is there a way to change these fields from required to not required in the uploading portion?

If I am incorrect about this, please let me know. :)

Thank you,

LAE

Comment: If you can be more specific about what fields you DO have, you might get a more useful answer.

Comment: Hello,   I am a market research programmer.  I am looking into CiviCRM to see if this is software has the ability to accomplish what I can need to collect clean data.   Most of the time, the client provides the records, which a decent portion are incomplete or blank fields such as First Name.  Our job is to fill in the missing pieces while we have the respondent on the phone or the web (based on the method that we are reaching out to the respondent).  I hope this helps explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a tele-research project you could fill the empty spaces with something like "UNKNOWN' or even 'UNKNOWN@UNKNOWN.com" and then import. You can then use the powerful search tools in Civi to find all the UNKNOWN's for your researchers to update.

Answer (score 2):

Contacts have to meet one of two criteria to be imported.

Either: First Name AND Last Name

Or: Email Address.

(in contrast to First name AND Last name AND Email Address).

Comment: In some cases, I only have a Last Name.  In general, do I have to use the First Name and Last Name and Email fields already programmed in CiviCRM? Or Can I create a new Custom Fields for these types of fields?

Comment: In my experience importing contacts where I only have an email address, and no first or last name data, the default importer rejects the record, wrongly stating "Missing required fields: First Name and Last Name OR Email Address"

Answer (score 1):

You can create different 'matching rules' that would work for import 'only email', or 'only first and last', but i am not sure if you are saying you have contacts that you want to import that have no email or first or last. if you do, then what do you know about them.